# Using jQuery tablesorter to sort mm/yy dates

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using the jquery tablesorter plugin to sort a table. On of my the columns in my table shows the date in mm/yy format.

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-name">...</td>
    ...
    <td rel="2000" class="col-dob">10/00</td>
    ...
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="col-name">...</td>
    ...
    <td rel="1986" class="col-dob">11/86</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

Note:

- Each cell has a unique class
- Date is displayed in the mm/yy format
- Cell with date receives the year as well

My jQuery code is as below:

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
$.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'user-birthdate',
        is: function(s) {
                // return false so this parser is not auto detected
                return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {
                // format your data for normalization

                var dateSplit = s.split('/');

                if(2 !== dateSplit.length)
                        return 0;

                return new Date(dateSplit[1], dateSplit[0], 1);
        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'numeric'
});

myClass.init = function() {
        $('.module .user table').tablesorter({
                sortList: [[0,0]],     
             widgets: ['zebra'],
                headers: {
                        5: {
                                sorter:'user-birthdate'
                        }
                }
        });
}

myClass.init();
```

My problem is that the tableSorter interprets 00 as year 1900 instead of 2000 and hence the sorted data is not correct.

Any clue how can I resolve this? I am using jQuery 1.2.6 and the latest version of tablesorter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tablesorter documentation is often rather unhelpful, I've found.  It *looks* like it says a lot, but is lacking in the details.

In this case, it doesn't tell you the function signature for a parser.  Fortunately, you can read [the unminified code](http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.js) to find it.

There we find that the `metadata` parser does this:

```
format: function(s,table,cell) {
```

This means that you can adjust your format method to:

```
format: function(s, table, cell) {
    // format your data for normalization

    var dateSplit = s.split('/');
    var year = $(cell).attr('rel');

    if(2 !== dateSplit.length)
        return 0;

    return new Date(year, dateSplit[0], 1);
},
```

Or at least similar to that.  I haven't actually tested this.  But it should be at least very close.

Comment: Thanks David. Waiting to test this on Monday. Will update here.

Comment: This was also useful in sorting a date column that had some blank values.  Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that your problem is the Date constructor and the 2-digit year string you are passing without disambiguation: `new Date(dateSplit[1], dateSplit[0], 1);`

I don't think you can (easily) get access to rel based on s in the parser.  Does s contain the entire contents of the cell?  Can you do something in the data in the cell like: `<span style="display : none">CC</span>MM/YY`, strip out the tags and then combine CC with YY in your parse?

Comment: Fortunately, the parser function gets passed the cell object as well.  See my answer.  :)