# Table Sorter is not working proprly

Tags: asp.net, tablesorter

I am using JQuery Table Sorter...Its working fine for all the fields except the **year field** in my grid view...**Year Field is  not sorted properly**

This is my code:

```
 $(function()
 {
   $("table[id$='gvInvoiceDetails']").tablesorter({ headers: { 4 : {sorter :
    "currency"}},textExtraction:"complex", widgets: ['zebra']
   }).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});                            
});
```

Any Suggesstions,Ideas,Samplecode

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out : [`Using jQuery tablesorter to sort mm/yy dates`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450936/using-jquery-tablesorter-to-sort-mm-yy-dates/452823#452823)