# Group list items with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, dom

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
 <li><span class="date">2011 05 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
 <li><span class="date">2011 05 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
 <li><span class="date">2011 04 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
 <li><span class="date">2011 04 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
 <li><span class="date">2010 03 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
 <li><span class="date">2010 02 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
</ul>
```

I need jQuery to group the items by both year AND month, like this:

```
<ul>
 <li class="year">2011
  <ul>
   <li class="month>May
    <ul>
     <li class="item"><span class="date">2011 05 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
     <li class="item"><span class="date">2011 05 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="month>April
    <ul>
     <li class="item"><span class="date">2011 04 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
     <li class="item"><span class="date">2011 04 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="year">2010
  <ul>
   <li class="month>March
    <ul>
     <li class="item"><span class="date">2011 03 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="month>February
    <ul>
     <li class="item"><span class="date">2011 02 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written a commented solution [**here** (*jsFiddle*)](http://jsfiddle.net/XbQ8t/5) and [**here** (*jsBin*)](http://jsbin.com/tayijahala/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

*(the two link have the same content, but jsFiddle is rather slow sometimes so you might want to go to jsBin instead)*

Hope you'll like it !

---

### HTML

```
<ul id="mainList">
    <li><span class="date">2011 05 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    <li><span class="date">2011 12 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    <li><span class="date">2011 05 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    <li><span class="date">2011 04 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    <li><span class="date">2011 04 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    <li><span class="date">2010 03 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
    <li><span class="date">2010 02 01</span><p>Text...</p></li>
</ul>
```

---

### JAVASCRIPT

```
// Month number to string
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

// Sorting the <li> by year
$("#mainList li").sort(function(a,b) {
    var yearA = $(a).children("span").text().split(" ")[0],
        yearB = $(b).children("span").text().split(" ")[0];
    return yearA < yearB;
}).appendTo($("#mainList"));

// Grouping the <li> by year
$("#mainList li").each(function() {
    var year = $(this).children("span").text().split(" ")[0];
    // If the grouping <li> doesn't exist, create it
    if ($("#mainList li.year." + year).length === 0) {
        $("#mainList").append($('<li class="year ' + year + '">' + year + '<ul></ul></li>'));
    }
    // Add the current <li> to the corresponding grouping <li>
    $(this).appendTo($("#mainList li.year." + year + " ul"));
});

// Sorting the <li> by month inside each grouping <li>
$("#mainList li.year ul").each(function() {
    $(this).children("li").sort(function(a,b) {
        var monthA = $(a).children("span").text().split(" ")[1],
            monthB = $(b).children("span").text().split(" ")[1];
        return monthA < monthB;
    }).appendTo($(this));
});

// Grouping the <li> by month inside each grouping <li>
$("#mainList li.year ul").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.children("li").each(function() {
        var month = $(this).children("span").text().split(" ")[1];
        // If the grouping <li> doesn't exist, create it
        if ($this.find("li.month." + month).length === 0) {
            $this.append($('<li class="month ' + month + '">' + months[month-1] + '<ul></ul></li>'));
        }
        // Add the current <li> to the corresponding grouping <li>
        $(this).appendTo($this.find("li.month." + month + " ul")).addClass("item");
    });
});
```

Comment: Amazing! That's the answer I was looking for :) .. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example of sorting alphabetically](http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/). I think this would be a good place to start. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction, but I'm more of a novice in jQuery to figure it out :) .. maybe there is a plugin for jQuery? I looked at TinySort but it doesn't seem to Group, only sort. And I need the "Grouping" part.

Comment: Hmm, well doing a quick search through SO, I found this article about sorting dates in a table. It seems like you may be able to do something like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450936/using-jquery-tablesorter-to-sort-mm-yy-dates

Comment: I don't see how that TableSorter helps me with my problem with lists. Maybe it's just more complicated then it seemed :( .. was hoping for an easy solution.