# How to group list items in an unordered list in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an unordered list of products with multiple groups. Each group can have one or many products and a product can be in any group. I want to group the products based on their group name.

Here the class name represents the group name.

```
<ul id="ulProdList">
<li class="NA">PP1</li>
<li class="A">PP1</li>
<li class="A">PP2</li>
<li class="A">PP3</li>
<li class="NA">PP4</li>
<li class="A">PP5</li>
<li class="B">PP1</li>
<li class="B">PP6</li>
<li class="NA">PP7</li>
<li class="NA">PP8</li>
<li class="B">PP2</li>
<li class="C">PP8</li>
<li class="NA">PP9</li>
</ul>
```

The result should be

```
<ul id="ulProdList">
<li class="NA">PP1</li>
<li class="A">PP1</li>
<li class="A">PP2</li>
<li class="A">PP3</li>
<li class="A">PP5</li>
<li class="NA">PP4</li>
<li class="B">PP1</li>
<li class="B">PP6</li>
<li class="B">PP2</li>
<li class="NA">PP7</li>
<li class="NA">PP8</li>
<li class="C">PP8</li>
<li class="NA">PP9</li>
</ul>
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: What is "their group name" the class or the text content? Your ordering is unclear to me...

Comment: class name is the group name

Comment: why isn't `NA` grouped together?

Comment: NA should not be grouped. Grouping is not applicable for NA.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079608/jquery-group-list-items-by-class) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110571/group-list-items-with-jquery/6111330)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery group list items by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079608/jquery-group-list-items-by-class)